# Ultimate Member

Tags: plugins

I just installed the Ultimate Member plugin and my site starts showing " This site has redirected you too many times". If I Deactivate the plugin, my site goes well, but immediately I reactivate the plugin again, the same issue. What could be the problem? I have already checked the settings of my WordPress to confirm the URL has no "www". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is occurring when you are visiting your website front end and you still have access to wp-admin.

Can you please go to the

```
Ultimate member -> Settings -> General -> Pages
```

and make sure you’ve correctly assigned Ultimate member pages there. Make sure your homepage of your website is NOT set as the UM logout page.